# Modify the query keyword in solr

Tags: solr, query-parser

When we get the query from front-end as "market survey rm", need to change it as "market survey system" in Solr and trigger the search. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Is that the only change you want to perform? Or do you want to translate `rm` to `system` everywhere?

Comment: only in query string we want that change

Comment: Yes, but is that the only term you want to change?

Comment: no, we have set of words which need to be changed in solr

Comment: Have you tried using a SynonymFilter?

Comment: Yes.. We want any other way to achieve this. Please let me know

Comment: Why didn't a synonymfilter work? This is .. what a synonymfilter is made for.